# Create Hash Table Within A Workbook

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I'm trying to create a hash table within a workbook, I've got it running in Parrallel for an automation account.

What I'm trying to achieve with this bit of code is to output what machine performed what action and at what time. I'm not 100% sure this would work in a workflow, but I've been trying to give it a go. Would appreciate some help understanding where I went wrong.

```
if($shouldStop -eq $true -and $scheduleAllowStop -eq $true){
    Write-Output "$($resource.Name) -- STOP --"
    $Action = 'STOP'
    [int]$TimeTaken = (Measure-command {Stop-AzureRmVm -Name $virtualMachine.Name -ResourceGroup $virtualMachine.ResourceGroupName -Force}).TotalMinutes
}
elseif($shouldStart -eq $true -and $scheduleAllowStart -eq $true){
    Write-Output "$($resource.Name) -- START --"
    $Action = 'START'
    [int]$TimeTaken = (Measure-command{Start-AzureRmVm -Name $virtualMachine.Name -ResourceGroup $virtualMachine.ResourceGroupName}).TotalMinutes
}
else{
    $Action = 'IGNORE'
    $TimeTaken = 0
    Write-Output "$($resource.Name) -- IGNORE --"
}

$result = @{
    VMName = $virtualMachine.Name
    Action = $Action
    TotalMinutes = $TimeTaken
}        

$output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $result
$output | Select-Object VMName, Action, TotalMinutes
```

Comment: Hi, I've created very similar scripts in Azure as runbooks. There's nothing obvious there that I can see that would cause an issue. I'm assuming you've authenticated with Azure RM? 'Login-AzureRmAccount' and selected a subscription using 'Get-AutomationPSCredential'?

Comment: Thanks @TimTharratt I've authenticated, i'm running in a workflow which is not producing an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hash like this, for the key you'd be best to use Azure's ID from the VM object as the are unique.

```
$result = @{}

# Declare the # before you loop through VMs

if($shouldStop -eq $true -and $scheduleAllowStop -eq $true){
    Write-Output "$($resource.Name) -- STOP --"
    $Action = 'STOP'
    [int]$TimeTaken = (Measure-command {Stop-AzureRmVm -Name $virtualMachine.Name -ResourceGroup $virtualMachine.ResourceGroupName -Force}).TotalMinutes
}
elseif($shouldStart -eq $true -and $scheduleAllowStart -eq $true){
    Write-Output "$($resource.Name) -- START --"
    $Action = 'START'
    [int]$TimeTaken = (Measure-command{Start-AzureRmVm -Name $virtualMachine.Name -ResourceGroup $virtualMachine.ResourceGroupName}).TotalMinutes
}
else{
    $Action = 'IGNORE'
    $TimeTaken = 0
    Write-Output "$($resource.Name) -- IGNORE --"
}

$resultObj = [PSCustomObject]@{

    VMName       = $virtualMachine.Name
    Action       = $Action
    TotalMinutes = $TimeTaken

}

$result.Add($virtualMachine.Name, $resultObj)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for that. It's not showing an output, do I need to do an `write-output` command? Also as this is a workflow do I need to add `inlinescript { code }`

Comment: Hi, yes if you want the output to be consumed by another run book. There's a good reference here [Runbook Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-output-and-messages). This isn't something I've experience of.